# Scarlet/Violet EVs transfer to BDSP?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet, pokemon-home, pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes

I have a BD team, if I send them to Violet and EV Train them, then transfer them back to BD, will the EVs stay?

Comment: I can't say for certain about BD, but I do this all the time with Sword And Scarlet. I'll move Pokemon into Sword, level to 100 and EV train, move back into Scarlet and level and EVs are maintained.

Comment: @Wondercricket if it works in Sword, then yes, it also works with BDSP. The only thing that changes between SV and BDSP is the moves learned (since that's how Pokémon home works). The only game where there's no EV transferal is PLA, since EVs don't exist there (We have Effort Levels instead)

Comment: I don't see why not, EV are calculated in the same way and are also stored on Pokemon Home